# Button disapper when write in textField ! Any help for this error?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

## I have a textField and button which binding with Keyboard, but when try to write in textField the button disapper and when  closing the keyboard the button

I use this function

```
func bindToKeyboard(){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keybordWillChange), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func keybordWillChange(_ notification : NSNotification){
let duration = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
let curve = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
let startingFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
let endingFrame = ( notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
let deltaY = endingFrame.origin.y - startingFrame.origin.y
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay:0.0, options: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {
    self.frame.origin.y += deltaY
    print(deltaY)


}, completion: nil)
}
```

i delegate textfield in ViewDidload

```
pointsGoalTextField.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your implementation, and it works fine. I just changed:

```
self.frame.origin.y += deltaY
```

into:

```
self.theButton.frame.origin.y += deltaY
```

so that the items on the top of the view don't disappear. there might be something else causing your button to disappear or it's one of the items in the top of the view

Comment: I tried it ,but Button disappeared when beginning writing